# How to remove ellipsis if element isn't wide enough

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML element that has the CSS properties of `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden`.  These work great in truncating the text when it's wider than the width of the div it's in and displaying the ellipsis.  However, if the div is resized smaller to the point where only the ellipsis is shown (*or when it's so small that it can't show the ellipsis and reverts to one character of the text*), I want it to remove the ellipsis altogether and not display anything.  Is that possible?

I don't really want to have to check the width of the text as that seems hackish. So I'd prefer something cleaner.

Comment: I doubt there is another option than that.

Comment: This is an example of where content queries would come in handy, but unfortunately they're still in the strawman phase of proposals.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/txduue3x/ You might want to use @media.

Comment: @Pangloss I do need ellipsis to display most of the time on a div, but when that div gets too small is when I want it to stop displaying the ellipsis and not show anything at all.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you mean `visibility: hidden;`?

Comment: Something along those lines would work but it's conditional on the div being at a size where only the ellipsis is displayed or less.

Comment: Can you post your html to a codepen or jsfiddle? Without seeing it we cant' be much help. Are you using a fluid layout? Is it responsive using media queries already?